# Flash Builder 4.6 | mx:DataGrid | Decimal to Fraction...or Fraction to Decimal Formatting

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder, fractions

My datagrid has a depth-dimensions column that shows fractions (one dimension used for example is 24 3/8). I have the ability to choose the text (fraction or decimal), but essentially I would need to be able to convert back and forth from **24 3/8** to **24.375**.

**Why the Decimal format is needed**:
I have checkboxes to filter the depth-dimensions column, so I'll need decimal form for that logic (e.g. checkbox to see filter depth-dimensions between 20 and 26).

**Why the fraction format is needed:** I'll need the fraction format because that depth-dimension data will be referenced as a string in another part of the application. The filter doesn't work when in this format is used in the dataGrid, because it won't recognize 24 3/8 as a number/int.

So basically I'm looking for a way to convert between the two formats, **24 3/8 to 24.375** and **24.375 to 24 3/8**.

Again, my apologies for the confusion - I'm able to re-edit and/or add more details if needed.

Thanks in advance!

--moe

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, fraction and decimal are the same thing in math. If you are not talking about math then say so and edit the question.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - I've updated the question a bit, does this help?

Comment: This still needs a translation to mean anything. In plain English this: "datagrid has dimensions" refers to the width and height of the component with cannot be formatted. On the other hand this "datagrid has a field called 'dimensions' with a text that shows either decimal or fractions". Rewrite the entire thing so it means something that other people can understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the fraction format is needed: I'll need the fraction format
>   because that depth-dimension data will be referenced as a string in
>   another part of the application.

Your reason for needing the fraction format seems odd. Do you understand that you can use a `Number` data type in a `String` by casting it?

```
        var decimalNum:Number = 3.14;

        //concatenating a Number with a String automatically casts it
        var autoCastString:String = "I want to eat some " + decimalNum;
        trace(autoCastString);

        // cast as String type
        var decimalString:String = String(decimalNum);

        trace("Mmmm! I like", decimalString);
```

Output:

```
I want to eat some 3.14
Mmmm! I like 3.14
```

But perhaps you have other reasons. The code below is from this link: [Decimal to Fraction](http://as3snippets.blogspot.com/2009/11/decimal-to-fraction.html). I haven't tested it.

```
package com.lookmum.util
{
    public class Fraction
    {
        private static var it         :Number = 0;
        public static var iterationLimit:Number = 10000;
        public static var accuracy    :Number = 0.00001;

        public function Fraction()
        {

        }

        private static  function resetIt():void
        {
            it = 0;
        }

        private static  function addIt():Boolean
        {
            it++;
            if (it == iterationLimit)
            {
                trace('error : too many iterations');
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function getFractionString(num:Number):String
        {
            var fracString:String;
            var fracArray:Array = getFraction(num);
            switch (fracArray.length)
            {
                case 1 :
                    fracString = num.toString();
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    fracString = fracArray[0].toString() + '/' + fracArray[1].toString();
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    fracString = fracArray[0].toString() + ' ' + fracArray[1].toString() + '/' + fracArray[2].toString();
                    break;
            }
            return fracString;
        }

        public function getFraction(num:Number):Array
        {
            var fracArray:Array = new Array();
            var hasWhole:Boolean = false;
            if (num >= 1)
            {
                hasWhole = true;
                fracArray.push(Math.floor(num));
            }
            if (num - Math.floor(num) == 0)
            {
                return fracArray;
            }
            if (hasWhole)
            {
                num = num - Math.floor(num);
            }
            var a:Number = num - int(num);
            var p:Number = 0;
            var q:Number = a;

            resetIt();

            while (Math.abs(q - Math.round(q)) > accuracy)
            {
                addIt();
                p++;
                q = p / a;
            }
            fracArray.push(Math.round(q * num));
            fracArray.push(Math.round(q));
            return fracArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you TOMATO! I will let you know once I get this going!